# checking internet connection

Tags: android

I use the following code for checking my internet connection.

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected() && ni.isAvailable())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected() && ni.isAvailable())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

but it says that I have the internet connection connection either the internet connection is disconnected or connected. and this method is called in the middle of the onCreate() method and  closes the application by the "back" button. Please help me on this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's completely unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: It always return "true" regardless if I am connected to internet or not.

Comment: The oncreate() method uses a parameter called savedInstanceState, would that be a problem to be happening this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this listening for Connectiviy broadcast intent. So create your broadcast receiver and in the `onReceive` callback check for:

```
boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
```

remember to filter the intent with `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`

Edit: look the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) doc

hope it helps

Comment: The oncreate() method uses a parameter called savedInstanceState, would that be a problem to be happening this.

Comment: Actually I do not understand what you mean. Could please reformulate

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add these these two permission code lines in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then in your java code:

```
 //declaration
    boolean net;

    //onCreate

    net = isOnline();

    if (net == true) {
                            //perform internet related task
                        } else  {
                            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    AddSite.this);

                            alert.setMessage(
                                    "No signal found or Internet connection is not connected.")
                                    .setTitle("Error")
                                    .setNeutralButton("OK",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method
                                                    // stub

                                                }
                                            }).show();
                        }

    //method

    public boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null;

            // return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();

        }
```

Comment: The oncreate() method uses a parameter called savedInstanceState, would that be a problem to be happening this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkConnection()
    {
        //ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (YourActivityClassName.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()&& conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Add this in the manifest file and then try.

Try with this. I used this in one of my project and it works fine for me.. Hope this will help you...

Comment: Are you getting error? If yes then plz provide error log. Because this works for my app...

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //---Check the internet connection---
    online = this.isOnline();
    Log.i("connection", Boolean.toString(online));
    //---Check the internet connection---  
    }
    public boolean isOnline() {
 ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isAvailable() && netInfo.isConnected()) {
         return true;
}
     return false;
 }
  }

Comment: I am trying and Eclipse does not seem to be knowing "AndroidLocationActivity" what should be done?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
Include this and then try...Hope this will resolve your problem...

Comment: The oncreate() method uses a parameter called savedInstanceState, would that be a problem to be happening this.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is communicating with a specific server (or domain) then you can use

```
try {
        InetAddress.getByName(SERVER).isReachable(CONNECTIVITY_TIMEOUT);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        //unknown host
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        //IO exception
    }
```

eg `SERVER=stackoverflow.com; CONNECTIVITY_TIMOUT=1000; // 1 second`

Comment: What is the declaration of "InetAddress" here ?

Comment: @ssrp its a java class.. import java.net.InetAddress; or simply Ctrl+Shift+o under Eclipse.

Comment: how could I know when the time out occurs?

Comment: @ssrp http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int) you get true if its reachable and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the permissions in manifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

If u r checking in emulator, U have to set the connection in settings.